# Beginning Equations in Code not being Shown in Output

Tags: python

Relatively new to Python. Equations I've written work alone, but I can't seem to figure out why only the last bit of the code is being shown in output.

I've tried using concatenation to no avail.

```
X = input('Enter X:')

Y = input('Enter Y:')

X1=int(X)

Y1=int(Y)

(X1+Y1)/(X1-Y1), (X1-Y1)**3, 

Answer = X1+Y1

print ('The last digit of X+Y is ' + str(Answer)[1])
```

I know the answer is most likely going to be quite simple, but any bit of advice helps!

Comment: is this in the console or file code?

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook

Comment: try doing `print((X1+Y1)/(X1-Y1), (X1-Y1)**3)`

Comment: I knew it would be simple! Cheers!

Comment: @Axiumin_ - move that to an answer, if you could.

Comment: oh that was it, will add.

Comment: Hey, I know this is late, but since my answer helped you, could you mark my answer as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In jupyter notebook by default give output at the end of the  line code in single code cell unless you explicitly define print statement

Eg:

```
    X=10
    X*3
    X*45
#op
450
```

In above code it will  give only last line output
If you had print statement every line then you will get all the line output

```
        X=10
        print(X*3)
        print(X*45)
    #op
    30
   450
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the last statement was being printed because that was the only one with a `print` statement. Just adding `print` to `(X1+Y1)/(X1-Y1), (X1-Y1)**3,` will fix the problem. So like this: `print((X1+Y1)/(X1-Y1), (X1-Y1)**3)`